# How count a mongodb collection with ReactiveMongoTemplate without any query filter?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, java-11, reactive-mongo-java

I would like to **determine mongodb collection size** in my java spring application. I know that reactive rective Mongo Template has a `count()` method what does that, however it needs a *query* param.

So my solution is:

```
public Mono<Long> collectionSize(){
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").exists(true);
    return this.reactiveMongoTemplate.count(Query.query(criteria),MY_COLLECTION_NAME);
}
```

However I dont like this solution, because I have to use a *captain obvious* criteria.

Is there any better solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Criteria` has an empty constructor.

```
public Mono<Long> collectionSize(){
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    return this.reactiveMongoTemplate.count(Query.query(criteria),MY_COLLECTION_NAME);
}
```

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#and-java.lang.String-)

And all of the variants of count requires a query param as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ReactiveMongoTemplate.html)

Query doesn't need criteria, you can just supply the query param. [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Query.html)

```
public Mono<Long> collectionSize(){
        return this.reactiveMongoTemplate.count(new Query(),MY_COLLECTION_NAME);
    }
```